# how populated grid view with the keys come from the session

Tags: asp.net, .net, arraylist

I want to create an online store web site.

I have created a datalist which shows my products in my site, I put the LinkButton in my datalist for getting the productID of the product which the user select and add it to shopping cart.

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="Add To Cart" CommandName="addtocart" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id")%>' >
```

When the user click the linkbutton this event fires:

```
protected void theDataList_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
//this add the selected product-id to the list<int> and put it in the 
//  session["addtocart"]
        if (e.CommandName == "addtocart")
        {                                 
            int productid = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            Label6.Text = productid.ToString();


            List<int> productsincart = (List<int>)Session["addtocart"];
            if (productsincart == null)
            {
                productsincart = new List<int>();
            }

            productsincart.Add(productid);

            Session["addtocart"] = productsincart;
}
```

After that when the user click the button which It's text is "show shopping cart",
the user will see the shoppingcart.aspx page

```
    Response.Redirect("shoppingcart.aspx");
```

in this page I have a gridview and I want to bind it to session["addtocart"];
when the page load the gridview show the selected products which their ids are in the session["cart"]
but it does not work and this error happened:
System.InvalidCastException: Object must implement IConvertible.

this is the related code:

```
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server"  
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"   >

           <columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" SortExpression="id" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="post" SortExpression="post" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="price" HeaderText="salary" 
                SortExpression="salary" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="color" HeaderText="years" SortExpression="years" />

        </columns>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:employeeConnectionString4 %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [products] WHERE ([productid] = @productid)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="7" Name="cart" SessionField="cart" 
                Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
```

I know the problem is related to the GridView3 and the Session["addtocart"],I Think the GridView3 can not convert the value from the Integer list object which is stored in the Session["addtocart"] to the Integer,It seems to me the error is coming from the conversion from the session object to the Integer List, but I Dont know how to solve this problem if any body help me I become so Thankful.

The Object in The Session["cart"] is an Integer list which contains the list of productsid that user has selected them to buy. 
It gives me this error:

Object must implement IConvertible.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Object must implement IConvertible.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

```
[InvalidCastException: Object must implement IConvertible.]
System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, TypeCode typeCode, IFormatProvider provider)   +2880621
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Parameter.GetValue(Object value, String defaultValue, TypeCode type, Boolean convertEmptyStringToNull, Boolean ignoreNullableTypeChanges) +141
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Parameter.GetValue(Object value, Boolean ignoreNullableTypeChanges) +63
System.Web.UI.WebControls.ParameterCollection.GetValues(HttpContext context, Control control) +301
System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.InitializeParameters(DbCommand command, ParameterCollection parameters, IDictionary exclusionList) +264
System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) +472
System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +19
System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +142
System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +73
System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind() +4
System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +82
System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls() +72
System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +87
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +44
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +842
```

Comment: Show us the following please: 1) what the cart object is, 2) the code that is giving you the error (the specific line). By looking at your code it looks like the problem is in your SqlDataSource, not the grid view.

Comment: The Object in The Session["cart"] is an Integer list which contains the list of productsid that user has selected them to buy.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your Sql Parameter. It can't cast type `List<int>` into Int32 as you're trying to do. And it looks like the List object does not implement iConvertible anyway, so you'll need a different approach.

I don't normally use SqlDataSource as you are doing, but here is a way you can build the proper syntax for the query you want:

Update your markup to this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:employeeConnectionString4 %>" />
```

Then on Page_Load, build your connection string like this:

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = String.Format("SELECT * FROM [products] WHERE [productid] in ({0}))", GetInValues(Session["cart"] as List<int>));
}
public string GetInValues(List<int> lst)
{
    System.Text.StringBuilder sValues = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    if (i == null)
        sValues.Append(0);
    else
    {
        foreach (int i in lst)
        {
            if (sValues.Length > 0)
                sValues.Append(", ");
            sValues.Append(i);
        }
    }
    return sValues.ToString();
}
```

Like I said, there may be a way to do this in the Markup, but it's not something I'm familiar with.

You could also create a class that inherits List and implement iCovertible, but I can't think of a way that's going to work as a SqlParameter. Plus the iConvertible interface is like 15 functions if I remember correctly, so it seems like a lot of work for just this one instance.